# Why my prediction function is giving error? ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)

Tags: python, testing, pytorch, image-segmentation

I'm trying to make prediction using the pre-trained model for binary segmentation using UNET and pytorch. Here is my code:
model.eval()   # Set model to evaluate mode

```
class SimDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, path, transform=None, isMask=False):
                
        self.m = ("test")
        self.path = path

        self.transform = transform
        self.isMask = isMask
    
    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.path)
    
    def __getitem__(self, idx):     
        one_image = os.path.join(self.m, self.path[idx]) # preparing image path/location
        img_temp = Image.open(one_image) # load RGB input image
        

        if self.transform:
            image = self.transform(img_temp)
      

        input_image = np.array(img_temp).astype('float32') # converting one image to np array
        input_image = np.transpose(input_image, (2, 0 ,1)) # converting from hwc to chw [(256,256,3) => (3, 256, 256)]
                
        return [input_image]

testlist = list(os.listdir(r"test"))
len(testlist)
image_datasets = {
    'testlist': testlist
}

dataset_sizes = {
    x: len(image_datasets[x]) for x in image_datasets.keys()
}
test_dataset = SimDataset(testlist, transform = trans, isMask=False)
test_loader = DataLoader(test_dataset, batch_size=3, shuffle=False, num_workers=0)
inputs, labels = next(iter(test_loader))
inputs = inputs.to(device)
labels = labels.to(device)

pred = model(inputs)
pred = torch.sigmoid(pred)
pred = pred.data.cpu().numpy()
print(pred.shape)
```

But it is showing error saying -> ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1).

Comment: Can you show how you build the model and what the full error is, including the line that causes it?

Answer (score 0):

Your code expects *two* outputs from the data loader:

```py
inputs, labels = next(iter(test_loader))
```

However, your `__getitem__` method in your dataset, returns only a *single* output:

```py
return [input_image]
```

Either you return *two* outputs from `__getitem__`, both images and labels.
Or expect only a *single* output from the `test_loader`.

Comment: Thank you. Fixed that but now it is showing AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'to' on the next line. How can I solve it?

Comment: @RameenRahman why does your `__getitem__` function returns a _list_ with `input_image`, why not just `input_image`? That is why `return [input_image]` and not `return input_image`?